# Eager loading with polymorphic association using conditions of another included association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, eager-loading

I have an activity feed and I want to eager-load all the activities that are present.

Each activity has an actor, which is polymorphic. Suppose there can be users or groups as actors.

Then I have a UserActivity table to know which activities are copied to which user.

Now, for the activity feed, I want to eager-load all the users and groups that are actors for each activity.

I have been reading and I know it will generate multiple SQL conditions because there is a polymorphic association to do the include. My sentence is now:

```
@activities = Activity.find(:all, :order=>"activities.updated_at DESC", :conditions => ['user_activities.user_id=?', @user.id], :include=> [:user_activities, :actor])
```

However, this raises an error:

> "Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :actor"

I tried the same, but without the conditions and it does work, generating only the SQL queries for the associations that are actors in the activities taken into account.  (Next sentence does work)

```
@activities = Activity.find(:all, :order=>"activities.updated_at DESC",  :include=> [ :user_activities, :actor])
```

But of course, this isn't what I want to do, because I want to have the condition, but I don't see a way of making it work. I have tried with where instead of the conditions option and it doesn't work, and I have used includes instead because I read that :include was deprecated for Rails 3.

It is very important for the application because it is the activity feed , so you can imagine it will generate a lot of traffic.

And I don't want to do a query each time the feed is reloaded for getting all users and groups that are in the activities, because if all the activities that are shown at one time didn't have one type of actor, I would do a SQL query that I could be saving.